# $http.get method of angularJS doesnot accept 5th parameter in URL string

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework, http-get

i am developing mobile application in cordova+angularJS in ionic framework. I am trying to send parameters in the get request body that is probably the request to get specific data based on input parameters. My query string is this:

```
var queryString = base_url + "get/requestChartData.php?userid=" + window.localStorage.userid + "&token=" + token + "&formid=" + formID  + "&questionid=" + questionID + "&chart=" + chartType;

$http.get(queryString, {}).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
.....
...
```

This request when i send to the server where PHP handles the request, send me back response as `<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: chart in....`

and even on my firebug debugging console, on the get request link when i expand, it shows me only four parameters instead of five.

is there any limit of sending number of parameters in the get request as a query string???

at PHP side i am doing this:

```
$userid = trim($_REQUEST['userid']);
$formid = trim($_REQUEST['formid']);
$fieldName = trim($_REQUEST['questionid']);
$chartType = trim($_REQUEST['chart']);
$token = trim($_REQUEST['token']);
```

i am not getting this one any resolution to it????

Comment: can you provide the whole printed queryString

Comment: Which parameter is not sent? Try checking in firebug to see what the value is.

Comment: the last one chart=" + chartType